# How to make script slow down in GoogleSheets Script Editor?

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I have a script thats attached below, and the problem I'm facing is that after it has keyed in "ticker" to Raw Data in b1, my entire sheet is never done loading and thus when its time to check if it's true or false AND copy the value it returns with False (mostly always) and #N/A #Error!.

All help is appreciated guys.

```
function compareCells(){
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();                   
  var listSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet18');                     
  var dataSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Raw Data');                    
  var listSheetLastRow = listSheet.getLastRow();                    
  var currRow = 2;                                                  

  for (i = 2; i <= listSheetLastRow; i++){                          
    var ticker = listSheet.getRange(currRow, 1).getValue();         
    dataSheet.getRange(1, 2).setValue(ticker);                      
    (Utilities.sleep(40000));                        
    var pe = dataSheet.getRange(7, 2).getValue();
    listSheet.getRange(currRow, 9).setValue(pe);

    var fcf = dataSheet.getRange(13, 2).getValue();
    listSheet.getRange(currRow, 10).setValue(fcf);

    var value1 = dataSheet.getRange(7, 2).getValue();               
    var value2 = dataSheet.getRange(13, 2).getValue();              

    if (value1 > 0.10 && value2 > 0.10){                             
      listSheet.getRange(currRow, 8).setValue('True');              
    }else{                                                          
      listSheet.getRange(currRow, 8).setValue('False');             
    }
    currRow++;                                                      
  }
}
```

I'm attaching the sheet that I'm working on here. https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/16cO8kyencBvUSdkDEJrhY7GL12JCpA32ipj4KaCBEHY/edit?usp=sharing Hopefully it helps

Comment: One thing I thought is worth mentioning is that if I add Browser.msgBox(pe + ' || ' + fcf); to the script ...it seems to delay just fine...its without it that I have trouble with.

Comment: i suggest that you avoid using the api calls within the for loop... get the entire sheet values into array outside the loop and iterate over the array

Comment: Could you elaborate further, I'm really a beginner into scripting. I could get the first value in list sheet and last value. But then I don't understand the other part.

Comment: Why don't you share a doc with us?

Comment: I'd reallly appreciate some help guys...!

Comment: When opening the linked file the following warning is displayed `File is in owner's trash. You won't be able to access this file soon.
If you still need access, please download it or copy and paste its contents`. Do you still want help with this question?